# "wollen" mit der Bedeutung von "werden"?

Tags: synonym, vocabulary, semantics

Ich war mir sicher, dass es – dem Englischen ähnlich – eine (heutzutage vielleicht veraltete) Bedeutung des Verbs "wollen", die sich zuweilen mit der Bedeutung von "werden" deckt, gibt. Weder der Duden noch Wiktionary weisen darauf hin, dass das vorkommen kann, aber nach einigem Stöbern bin ich auf Sätze aus Grimms Märchen gestoßen, die wiederum darauf schließen lassen, dass es doch möglich ist:

Hans im Glück

> geschieht Euch so ein großer Gefallen, so will ich Euch wohl die Kuh für das Pferd vertauschen.

Froschkönig

> wenn du mir das versprichst, so will ich hinunter steigen und dir die goldene Kugel wieder herauf holen.

Gevatter Tod

> Willst du mich zum Paten deines Kindes nehmen, so will ich ihm Gold die Hülle und Fülle und alle Lust der Welt dazu geben.

Hab jetzt auf die Schnelle nur Grimms Märchen als Beispiele gefunden, aber ich bin mir ziemlich sicher es schon öfters gelesen/gehört zu haben. Kann sich "will" also semantisch mit "werde" decken, oder übersehe ich hier etwas?

Comment: Wäre eine interessante Parallele zum Englischen.

Comment: Ungewöhnlich ist das nicht. wollen/sollen gibt es auch in anderen germanischen Sprachen als Futur-Hilfsverb.

Comment: @Veredomon und Grantwalzer - wird dennoch immer als "false friend" beigebracht.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, es kann sich decken, denn die Modalverben haben, je nach Gebrauch, öfter eine starke Zukunftskomponente:

> Du musst Dein Zimmer aufräumen!
>   Du sollst Dein Zimmer aufräumen!
>   Du darfst ins Kino gehen.
>   Ich will in die Stadt gehen.

Anzunehmen ist, dass das jeweils mit dem Hauptverb ausgedrückte Ereignis zum Sprechzeitpunkt in der Zukunft liegt. Es wäre auch seltsam zu sagen, „Ich will nach London fliegen!“, wenn der Flieger gerade in London landet.

Es gibt auch Positionen, die „werden“ den Status eines Hilfsverbs absprechen und das Futur als rein modale Konstruktion sehen – Ulrich Engel beispielsweise, am Ende dieses [Dokuments](http://www.fb10.uni-bremen.de/khwagner/tempus/pdf/Engel.pdf).

Ich sehe den wesentlichen Unterschied jedoch darin, dass das werden-Futur universell verwendbar ist.

Comment: I came here wondering about a verse in a song: *Ach, Liebster, könntest du schwimmen, so schwimme doch her zu mir, drei Kerzen* **will** *ich anzünden: die sollen leuchten dir*.  It is readily translated with the future in my book—among other oddities in the translation of this song (e.g., that it seems he cannot swim but still goes for a dip).  Does this fit your explanation, or is it just old-style?